# Shemona Veshishim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred sixty-eight?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible.*

*At some point between twenty-four hours and a few days from now, I will:*

- *Vote up all interesting, relevant answers.*
- *Accept what I consider the "best" answer.*
- *Move on to the next number.*

*Yesterday's lazy gematria was missing. Today's is "חָסֵר".*

Comment: Groan. (Chars.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both Rabbi Yitzchak Abarbanel and Rabbi Yehudah Mintz died in the year 268 of the 6th millennium (5268 = 1508). [See Ozar Hamisparim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37998&hilite=0d724ac5-ce6b-40f6-afa1-9d9dbf4776aa&st=%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%97&pgnum=351) published in 1942 and [available](http://hebrewbooks.org/37998) at hebrewbooks.org

Comment: mocdeg, welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for pointing us to this excellent resource! Please consider registering your account, to help the site keep track of your contributions no matter where you log in from.

Comment: Re Yitzchak Abarbanel: 268 is just a guess for the year of his death based on his tombstone. It remains a mystery how [he claimed to have written his commentary on Bereshis in the year 282](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14387&st=&pgnum=441).

Comment: @jake: that would be difficult for other reasons anyway, because Spain took over control of Naples in 1503, so it would have been difficult for him to have still been there in 1522 (although it is true that the Jews weren't formally expelled from there until 1541). I wonder whether perhaps the date 282 is according to some other counting of the years since Creation; Abarbanel himself does have his own views on biblical chronology differing from the standard, such as that Shaul ruled for 17 or 20 years (as compared to the 2 years that Seder Olam assigns him).

Comment: @Alex, IIRC Abarbanel does indeed have his own views on chronology, and at least intended to write a book about it (if he did, it is lost), but he is at least consistent with the standard count of years since creation; that is, he would not deny that this year is 771. In fact, he ended all of his books with their dates of completion, all in terms of the standard calendar.